# Can't start a bounty without the mouse

Tags: bug, bounties, accessibility

It's currently impossible to start a bounty without the mouse. Trying to <kbd>tab</kbd> to the "start a bounty" skips right over it; going from "add a comment" to the link to the question in the "share a link" thing.

You should be able to tab to the button, press enter, select an amount using the arrow keys, continue, select a reason using either the arrow keys or numbers, continue, write a custom message, and start the bounty.

<sub>If you're confused as to why it's important that things be accessible without the mouse, please read up on [keyboard accessibility](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/). While I thankfully don't have any physical problems with using 
a mouse, I'm using my time with a broken mouse to give accessibility feedback so that people who need it can get a better site experience.</sub>

Comment: As a workaround, try executing this in the browser console: `$(".bounty-link").click();`