# Changes to the close dialogue have broken keyboard shortcuts for closing a post

Tags: bug, status-completed, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts, close-dialog

When using the keyboard shortcuts previously, you could press <kbd>m</kbd>, for "moderation", and then <kbd>c</kbd> for "close", to open the close dialogue. This still works. However, after that, you can no longer press <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>3</kbd> or whatever to select a close *reason*; it just shows "no shortcuts available".

[image: close dialogue, showing "no shortcuts available" on the side]

Can we please fix this so that keyboard shortcuts work again for this? I tend to use this a lot, personally, and keyboard shortcuts are a big part of accessibility (as I've gone on about here on Meta.SE previously).

Comment: I note that they managed to not break the same functionality in the flag dialog. So it's probably not too hard to reinstate. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUVcR.jpg

Comment: Please move or copy this to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/256282

Comment: @curiousdannii - done

Answer (score 5):

Keyboard shortcuts for the close menu are now working

> with just one finger
> click `m`, then `c`, then number
> close vote registered